# Allocate a full width image in a box with TCPDF

Tags: image, tcpdf

I am in the process of finishing a project on jelix to edit a pdf from a page. I'm just starting out so I don't have all the right reflexes yet.
At the top of my page, I have the title "Roadmap" and, it is not essential, but instead of a text I would have liked to put an image, full width (in the box, of the same way as text) much like a banner. I would like to center it by the way as well.

How can I do it, what method to use.

There currently it looks like this:

[image]

```
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Feuille de route', 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 0);
```

I thought using

```
$pdf->Image('C:\Users\testjelix\image.jpg', '', '', 40, 40, '', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
```

but it is superimposed on the boxes, it is placed below I don't know how to handle the syntax

```
"Image($file, $x='', $y='', $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='', $align='', $resize=false, $dpi=300, $palign='', $ismask=false, $imgmask=false, $border=0, $fitbox=false, $hidden=false, $fitonpage=false)"
```

Could you just guide me a bit? thank you
------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

I succeeded but I don't understand how to make sure that the image is not below the rest of the table I am creating. There for the moment it is superimposed on the rest. How to leave the image above the rest?

I've done it with :

```
$pdf->Image('C:\Users\testjelix\image.jpg', '', '', "", "", '', '', 'T', false, 300, 'C', false, false, 1, false, false, true);
```

I don't know how to skip a line after the image to get the continuation of the table

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. I add a line break this way

```
$pdf->Ln(40);
```